# How do I make the input case-insensitive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How to handle the input string so that all correctly spelled words are treated the same, insensitive to the case?

For example: 
Input `January` in any form as long as it is spelled correctly. 
Here, `january`, `JANUARY`, `JaNuArY` - should be treated the same.

```
m = input("What month were you born?\n")
d = input("What day were you born?\n")
y = input("What year were you born\n")

months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

print("Your birthday is " + str(months.index(m)+1) + "/" + d + "/" + y)
```

Comment: You can add .capitalize() method to input function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .lower() or .upper() or [.lower() and .capatalize()] according to how you store your months in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Although other answers give you enough to solve your problem, since you mentioned python dictionaries in the question, here's a bit faster, neater approach -

• Lookup in List in `O(n)` while in Dictionary is `O(1)`

```
months = {"January": '1', "February": '2', "March": '3', "April": '4', "May": '5', "June": '6', "July": '7', "August": '8', "September": '9', "October": '10', "November": '11', "December": '12'}

m = input("What month were you born?\n")
d = input("What day were you born?\n")
y = input("What year were you born?\n")

print("Your birthday is {0}/{1}/{2}".format(months[m.lower().capitalize()], d, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

change input to that:

```
d = input("What day were you born?\n").lower()
y = input("What year were you born\n").lower()
```

this will turn every string to all-lowercase string

[source](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower)

Answer (score 0):

Use `lower()` and `string.capitalize()` function on your input:

```
d = "jaNuARY"

d.lower().capitalize()
Out[2]: 'January'
```

This way you will always get a same spelling of any input - January instead of JANUARY etc, matching your dictionary.

It is also good solution since you don't need to alter your dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You should first use lowercase names in your `months` list. It should look like this:

```py
months = ["january", "february", ...]
```

Use the `lower()` method to convert the input to lowercase.

```py
m = input("What month were you born?\n").lower()
```

Therefore, the received input will always be in lowercase and you can just use `index` like you did originally.